# How to avoid the DbgCommand command being written to the logfile

Tags: python, windbg, pykd

I'm having an annoying issue with `Pykd.pyd`: I'm using it in a script, launching several `DbgCommand` functions, like:

```
DbgCommand("dt 0x000000eab8748430 CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *> m_nCount")
```

This for getting the size of the `CMap` object. As this is done in a script, using lots and lots of objects, I am using logfiles in `Windbg` (menu `edit`, `Open/Close Log File`), and here's the catch:
When looking at this in `Windbg` window, I only see the results of the `DbgCommand` calls, but in the logfile I see the command itself too:

`Windbg` window:

```
000000eab87488f0    CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *>  Size:[0]  // formatted DbgCommand result
000000eab8748930    CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *>  Size:[0]  // formatted DbgCommand result
```

Logfile:

```
dt 0x000000eab87488f0 CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *> m_nCount // DbgCommand command
000000eab87488f0    CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *>  Size:[0]  // formatted DbgCommand result
dt 0x000000eab8748930 CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *> m_nCount // DbgCommand command
000000eab8748930    CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *>  Size:[0]  // formatted DbgCommand result
```

How can I avoid `DbgCommand` commands being written to the logfile?

Meanwhile I've found out that a parameter `suppressoutput` exists, which can be used for not showing the result of the command on screen, but this is not what I mean, as you can see in following excerpts:

test-script excerpt:

```
dprintln("1 : x /2 <application_name>!CStringList::CStringList, true")
dbgCommand("x /2 <application_name>!CStringList::CStringList", True)
dprintln("2 : x /2 <application_name>!CStringList::CStringList, false")
dbgCommand("x /2 <application_name>!CStringList::CStringList", False)
dprintln("3")
```

Result on screen:

```
1 : x /2 <application_name>!CStringList::CStringList, true
2 : x /2 <application_name>!CStringList::CStringList, false
004b6d3e          <application_name>!CStringList::CStringList
3
```

Result in logfile:

```
1 : x /2 <Application>!CStringList::CStringList, true
x /2 <Application>!CStringList::CStringList
004b6d3e          <Application>!CStringList::CStringList
2 : x /2 <Application>!CStringList::CStringList, false
x /2 <Application>!CStringList::CStringList
004b6d3e          <Application>!CStringList::CStringList
3
```

It seems that `suppressoutput` is meant for not showing `DbgCommand` result on screen, while I'm interested in not showing `DbgCommand` input in the logs.

Let me explain what's wrong with the `typedvar` solution:

For some strange reason, `CMap` and `CArray` objects can't be used in a simple way (standard `windbg` command), as you can see here:

```
0000000000335e90    <application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const * __ptr64,int,int>
```

As you can see, `dt` does not work on this:

```
dt 0x0000000000335e90 <application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const * __ptr64,int,int>
Symbol <application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const * __ptr64,int,int> not found
```

This can be handled by removing the `<application_name>` and `__ptr64` (don't forget the space):

```
0:000> dt 0x0000000000335e90 CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const *,int,int>
<application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const *,int,int>
   +0x000 __VFN_table : 0x00000001`3fc77ac8 
   +0x008 m_pHashTable     : (null) 
   +0x010 m_nHashTableSize : 0x11
   +0x018 m_nCount         : 0n0
   +0x020 m_pFreeList      : (null) 
   +0x028 m_pBlocks        : (null) 
   +0x030 m_nBlockSize     : 0n10
```

This seems to correspond with following `x /2 *!*` result:

```
00000001`3fc77ac8 <application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const * __ptr64,int,int>::`vftable'
```

However if I try to use `typedVar` it seems not to work:

```
if type_name.find("CMap<") != -1:
    dprintln("original type name : [%s]" % type_name)
    dprintln(("pointer : [0x" + pointer_format + "]") % ptr)
    var =  typedVar(type_name, ptr) # before translation of __ptr64
    nieuwe_grootte1 = var.m_nCount
    type_name = type_name.replace(application_name + "!","") # Normally type_name starts with "<application_name>!CMap<...", it must become "CMap<..."
    type_name = type_name.replace(" __ptr64","")             # apparently, when the CMap definition contains __ptr64, it doesn't work
                                                             # dt 0x000000eab8748430 CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *> m_nCount seems to work

    dprintln("after replacements type name : [%s]" % type_name)
    var =  typedVar(type_name, ptr) # after translation of __ptr64
    nieuwe_grootte2 = var.m_nCount

    grootte_result = dbgCommand(("dt 0x" + pointer_format + " %s m_nCount") % (ptr,type_name)).split(' : ')
    grootte = grootte_result[-1].split('\n')[0] # list[-1] is Python for "take the last entry of a list"
    grootte = grootte.replace("0n","")
    dprintln((pointer_format + "\t%s\t Size:[%s, %d, %d]") % (ptr, type_name, grootte, nieuwe_grootte1, nieuwe_grootte2))
```

This gives following results:

```
original type name : [<application_name>!CMap<unsigned int,unsigned int,enum CService::PARAMETER_TYPE,enum CService::PARAMETER_TYPE>]
pointer : [0x00000000003355e0]
after replacements type name : [CMap<unsigned int,unsigned int,enum CService::PARAMETER_TYPE,enum CService::PARAMETER_TYPE>]
00000000003355e0    CMap<unsigned int,unsigned int,enum CService::PARAMETER_TYPE,enum CService::PARAMETER_TYPE>  Size:[105, 105, 105]
original type name : [<application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const * __ptr64,int,int>]
pointer : [0x0000000000335640]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\heap_stat_extra.py", line 215, in <module>
    var =  typedVar(type_name, ptr) # before translation of __ptr64

TypeException: <application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const * __ptr64,int,int> : invalid type name
```

I have already tried removing `<application_name>` and/or `__ptr64` but it seems not to solve the issue. Moreover, the result of `dt` and "x /2 *!*" (this does not format correctly) clearly indicate that the mentioned type is present. It seems that `typedVar` has real problems dealing with the `__ptr64` tag. Is there a workaround for this?

***Edit***
I've just tried, using the Python commands from pykd_team, but still it seems not to be working (this time on `CArray` objects), as you can see:

Launching my script gives following result:

```
  File "C:\Temp_Folder\blabla\heap_stat_logs_backup.py", line 232, in <module>
    collection_Size = typedVar(type_name, ptr).m_nCount

TypeException: CArray<CSyncRules::VersionRestriction *,CSyncRules::VersionRestriction * const &> : invalid type name
```

Trying to investigate what's the correct classname:

```
0:000> !py
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> app = pykd.module("<Application>")
>>> for tp in app.enumTypes("*CArray*"):
...   print tp
... 
CArray<CSyncRules::VersionRestriction *,CSyncRules::VersionRestriction * const &>
...
```

As you can see, the classname is an exact match, but yet there's a `TypeException`. Do you have any idea what to do now? (By the way, I'm working with Visual Studio Professional 2017)

***New edit***

Most probably the issue is caused by PYKD, not being able to handle the asterisk signs (`*`) in the type definitions. Is there any escape character I can use in order to avoid the mentioned problems?

Comment: You can get the result of the command in PyKd as a string and then write it to a file yourself

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @pykd_team: do you have some more information? I've edited the question after my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pykd.typedVar class. It is specialy designed for such cases

Comment: How to you mean?

Comment: I just had a look at "https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/wikis/User-Manual-rus" but the part about TypedVar class seems not to be elaborated yet, or is it available elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

try to change:

```
dt 0x000000eab87488f0 CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *> m_nCount
```

to:

```
var =  typedVar("CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *>", 0x000000eab87488f0 )
print var
print var.m_nCount
print var.m_nCount * 2
```

You can get access to any filed of CMap class and work with its as they are natural python types

If you are going to get typedVar multiple times you can cache type information to avoid performance problems:

```
CMap = typeInfo("CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *>")
var = typedVar( CMap, 0x000000eab87488f0 )
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the `typedvar` solution seems not to be working, at least not for some `CMap` and `CArray` objects, I'm updating the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enumerate types for your module ( with wildcard mask ) and find exact symbol name for CMap.

```
app = pykd.module("<application_name>")
for tp in app.enumTypes("CMap*"):
   print tp
```

I can try to reproduce an issue on a small example, but I need to know your Visual Studio version.

Comment: I've updated the question. Do you have an idea how to proceed?