# How to read heap using PYKD

Tags: python, windbg, pykd

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651846/how-to-avoid-the-dbgcommand-command-being-written-to-the-logfile), I wanted to replace `DbgCommand("dt ...")` by an API call, and the `PYKD` command `typedVar()` came to the rescue.

As a result, my heap_stat script (extended with `m_nSize` and `m_nCount` information) is running three times faster now.

For your information, I've done this replacement for calculating the amount of members in an STL collection:

```
Replace: collection_Size = dbgCommand(("dt 0x" + pointer_format + " %s m_nSize") % (ptr,type_name)).split(' : ').[-1].split('\n')[0]
By:      collection_Size = typedVar(type_name, ptr).m_nSize
```

As a result of this success, I'd like to replace other `DbgCommand` requests by API calls.

For the case of `dbgCommand('!heap -h 0')`, this seems not to be that simple (some examples):

```
>>> for t in targetHeapIterator():
...   print t
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: This class cannot be instantiated from Python

>>> for t in targetHeap().entries:
...   print t
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: This class cannot be instantiated from Python

>>> for t in targetProcess().getManagedHeap().entries:
...   print t
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

How can I iterate over the heap of my process (replacing `!heap -h 0`)?

P.S. Even if `targetHeap()` can't be used as a replacement for `!heap -h 0`, I'd still like to know how to use it, for investigation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

targetHeapIterator() - only for managed heap and it cannot be created directly, only through special class.

```
for entry in targetProcess.getManagedHeap().entries():
    pass # enumerate managed heap
```

For enumerating native heap, you need write your own script.

Maybe it will be useful for you:
https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykdwin

This package has heap enumeartor but with restrictions:

- does not support LFH
- does not support Segment Heap

Sample from doc:

```
from pykdwin.heap import *
for heap in get_heaps():
    for entry in heap.entries():
        print( hex(entry.address), entry.size )
```

Comment: "It does not support LFH" - be careful, you may not see small allocation

And  this script has not been tested on old OS, only 8.1/10